# AWS-SDK Rails 3.1 Ruby 1.9.3 Writes fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I can read from my amazon bucket, but write kept failing.

```
  s3 = AWS::S3.new
  bucket = s3.buckets['tmp']
  obj = bucket.objects["test.rtf"]
  obj.write(:file => "/Volumes/.../test.rtf")
```

It will Seg fault. No useful information is given to help me debug it. Any ideas? 
I am using AWS-SDK gem, Rails 3.1.3, Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my HTTP/SSL library was broken because I used to use Port and I switch to RVM. Ruby was pointing to both libraries and the HTTP/SSL library was causing the error. I remove SSL library and reinstalled it using RVM. It solved the error.

Answer (score 3):

You're on OSX aren't you...

I have had all kinds of issues with my RVM / FOG (much the same as AWS) / OSX setup on Lion. It seems to be related to the compiler (GCC LLVM).

Here is what I do for a build (that works for me at least):

```
#!/bin/sh
RUBY_VER=1.9.3-p0
rvm reload
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm remove ${RUBY_VER}
rvm install ${RUBY_VER} --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

If you're not using RVM, then this won't help. But as far as I can tell RVM isn't the problem.

I would also make sure that all my gems are reinstalled after this is done.

Comment: Thanks! fixed the problem for mee too.